# Simple payload encryption in C++

Tags: c++, encryption, tcp, aes

I have different applications that must communicate among themselves. They can use both UDP and TCP and there can be more than one link between two specific applications. My idea is to encrypt the communications using AES, storing the password somewhere in the computer (encrypted). The password that will be used is of course the same for all the applications and will be changed once in a while. The language I'm using is C++ and I was thinking to use libcrypto++ but I'm open to suggestions.

I know about OpenSSL, TLS etc but what I'd like to do is a really simple encryption of the payload of my custom application protocols. Is there any particular problem that I should pay attention to when implementing this, like message boundaries etc?

Another question is: is it possible to only get the shared key from a central server via SSL or other, and then use this for the above encryption? this will be done from the application at startup and the password could be stored in RAM.

Comment: This is a recipe for poor insecure encryption. Start learning how to use OpenSSL, they have plenty of examples.

Comment: Yes, but what if I haven't a bidirectional channel, OpenSSL requires an handshake phase

Comment: _OpenSSL requires an handshake phase_ - not necessarily. Read up on OpenSSL, there is no point in reinventing a square wheel.

Comment: Ok, I was speaking about TLS in particular. I didn't know about this feature in OpenSSL. Thank you

Comment: what if I have the application I've talked about with N connections to another application and I wanted to avoid key / algorithm negotiation every time but do it just once and use the password for all of them. Is it still possible doing it with OpenSSL or is there some already existing protocol that does that?

Comment: You can use OpenSSL encryption algos directly without session key exchange. But again, you had better not reinvent the wheel. Have each of your actors use a certificate (file) with a public/private key and do certificate based authentication and key exchange.

Comment: thank you, I'll think about that